# Tomcat JDBC Count failed Logins

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am currently trying to find the best method for counting failed login attempts in my database when logging in via JDBC connection in tomcat.

Has anyone ever used this method before? I don't really know where I can catch it to add in some logic. Thoughts?

Comment: Just scan the log file for 403s.

Comment: If I wanted to add a login failed count and a block user after 3 fails. How could this be implemented? Would a custom realm be more effective?

Answer (score -1):

The getConnection() method of either DataSource or DriverManager will throw a SQLException if the login fails. You can catch the exception and do whatever you like (increment a counter, log the failure) in the catch block.

But normally, an application will use the same connection info (stored in property files, for instance) and would not fail for that reason once you configured your application correctly. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You've missed the point. He isn't logging in to the database, he is using the Tomcat JDBC Realm to perform user logins by looking up the database.

Comment: Correct EJP - The complication is in using the JDBC Connection with Tomcat to connect to the DB

Comment: @ColinDawson No, the complication is in getting the Tomcat JDBC Realm to log access failures. Nothing to do with the database connection. If that doesn't work, nothing works, and you have a rather easy problem to debug.

Comment: @EJP - Understood. My wording was bad. Though trying to get the JDBC realm to log these failures I thought would have been standard functionality in the realm. Any idea how this can be done?